# Replace a string in a text read from a csv and save it

Tags: c#, csv

I managed to load the csv and now want to change a few strings inside and then save it again.

First problem: He doesnt want to change the text to '0 . Replacing only "4" with "0" works, but never when my string has more than 1 character.

Second problem: The last replace where I delete all **'** to "". When opening the csv in an editor it shows some weird asian characters instead of nothing.
(䈀攀稀甀最猀瀀爀)

There are no spaces in my csv. The csv looks like

> .....";"**++49** then more random numbers and so on.

This is just the part where ++49 is to be found.

Relevant code:

```
Encoding ansi = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252); 

            foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"path comes here, "*.csv"))
            {

                string text = File.ReadAllText(file, ansi);
                text = text.Replace(@"++49", "'0");
                text = text.Replace("+49", "'0");
                text = text.Replace(@"""", "");
                File.WriteAllText(file, text, ansi);
            }
```

Am i doing something fundamentally wrong?

edit: What it looks like: `";"++49<morenumbers>";;` What it should look like:  `;0<morenumbers>;;`

Comment: Please show a sample of the input CSV and then what the output should look like.

Comment: When you have [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake), you have an encoding problem. We can't reproduce this from the information you show. Just take a look at `text` in your code. You're probably reading an UTF-16 encoded file as ANSI, which won't work.

Comment: you code work for me fine, but, could you please say encoding is your file in?

Comment: Debug steps: 1) start with a single csv file of a few lines, 2) step through the code (debugger) and inspect what is read from the file and the replacement results. 3) don't overwrite the input but write to a different file - add an extra .csv extension 4) inspect the new file. Please share input file and results.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. It indeed was an encoding problem. The file was in UTF-16 LE little-endian (Unicode) (1200 Unicode). I open it with code 1200, replace my things and save it with code 1252.

Answer (score 0):

As people mentioned in comments, problem is with your file encoding decoding. So in this case you can try this:

```
 foreach(string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"path comes here","*.csv"))
            {
                Encoding ansi;
                using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(file, true))
                {
                    ansi = reader.CurrentEncoding; // please tell what you have here ! :)
                }
                string text = File.ReadAllText(file, ansi);
                text = text.Replace(@"++49", "'0");
                text = text.Replace(@"+49", "'0");
                text = text.Replace(@"""", "");
                File.WriteAllText(file, text, ansi);
            }
```

For me it works fine with all formats I was able to set. Then you do not have to set your encoding as hardcoded value

Comment: The file i get send is in UTF-16 LE little-endian . But the software I work with needs it in Ansi. Thx for the help :)